# Events on existing administrative labels in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

## Problem

When viewing Google maps in Chrome, I can click on a city/state/country name and it will select that place as if I had searched for it using the search bar. I want to recreate part of that functionality within the custom Google map I am creating. (works in Chrome, Firefox, but not ie.)

When the name of a city/state/country is clicked on within the map, I would like to retrieve the name that was clicked so that I can use that to query a separate database that has facility information for where I work.

For example, if you click on the word "Minneapolis" in the following map, it will populate the search bar with "Minneapolis."
https://www.google.com/maps/@44.970697,-93.2618534,12z

## What I tried

Using the developer tools I investigated how this event works but was not able to get anywhere. Triggering the event and logging it in the timeline creates a mouse click event with multiple function calls:

(VM1027 @44.970697,-93.2618534,12z:209) - Which seems to be passing the lat/long data to tell it where to focus.

(rs=AItRSTODIRMz3n8HrbIzjA2FcMR8xQLkKg:416) - no idea what this is doing

Also looked for the code that holds the "Minneapolis" label by searching through the page sources. I also looked for a custom map that made use of this type of event, but have not been able to find one.

I was honestly hoping to just run some javascript to add an onclick event to all the city, state, country labels; but I do not know how to select the labels. I know I can add an event to markers using:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infoWindow.open(myMap, marker);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What specific problem are you having? You'll need to provide more details :).

Comment: I have mostly been looking online through the API documentation, it might be something the API doesn't support yet, but it does work on maps.google.com so I am not sure. Details above.